# DomainException after clean Docker installation

Tags: magento2, cli, default, domain, docker

I used a Docker configuration for Magento which I found  [here](https://medium.com/@ju5t_/how-we-build-our-magento-2-environment-using-docker-and-continuous-integration-8a6177b8aa5b). I used the files in the [example folder](https://github.com/sensson/docker-magento2/tree/master/example) to get myself started. After finishing the installation I went to see if the CLI options are working. They have issues:

```
sudo bin/magento indexer:info
```

returns

```
[DomainException]
Connection "default" is not defined
```

and

```
sudo bin/magento cache:flush
```

returns

```
[DomainException]
Default website is not defined
```

after disabling cache with

```
sudo bin/magento cache:clean
```

and trying to clean or flush the cache again, the following message appeared:

```
[Exception]
Notice: Undefined index: websites in /home/goran/Magento_2/magneto2-beeit/src/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php on line 248
```

Also

```
sudo bin/magento config:show
```

returns

```
Configuration for path: "" doesn't exist
```

I went and checked `store_website` table and `is_default` column. There is number 1 in the row for the Main Website, so the default website should be set?

Questions:

1. What is "default connection" and how to define it?
2. How to define default website?

[Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml - gist](https://gist.github.com/TerrorSquad/3f9e1ce4481254467e69468f5b1ffa23)